# Facebook Javascript SDK open-graph: error adding custom objects for custom stories

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, sdk, facebook-opengraph

I've created a custom object, called 'Opinion' to build custom stories around it.

I'm trying to add some app-owned objects from my website using the javascript sdk.

The sample code facebook gives me is:

```
FB.api(
  'me/objects/[namespace]:opinion',
  'post',
  {
    app_id: xxxxxxxx,
    type: "[namespace]:opinion",
    url: "http://samples.ogp.me/331257847005141",
    title: "Sample Opinion",
    image: "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png",
    description: ""
  },
  function(response) {
    // handle the response
  }
);
```

The reponse is an error (OAuth Exception):

```
2500: Cannot specify type in both the path and query parameter.
```

If i remove the `type` parameter, i get another error:

```
(#100) The parameter object is required
```

Same if I remove `[namespace]:opinion` from the path.

I don't understand why, and there's no reference about this after googling it.

Why this? Any resource i can refer to solve that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The object is a JSON-encoded version of an object, the sample code generated for you was incorrect. Also remove type from the parameter list.

So something like,

```
FB.api(
  'me/objects/[namespace]:opinion',
  'post',
  {
    object: {"app_id":xxx,"url":"http:\/\/samples.ogp.me\/331257847005141","title":"\"Sample Opinion\"","image":"https:\/\/s-static.ak.fbcdn.net\/images\/devsite\/attachment_blank.png","description":"\"\""}
  },
  function(response) {
    // handle the response
  }
);
```

An example of how it looks can be seen at http://philippeharewood.com/facebook/objectify.html and it was based off the curl example given at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-object-api/

Comment: Shame on you Facebook docs. That example is still official in Facebook docs.

Comment: Just thought that I would point out that for me to get this working I had to remove "/objects" from the first parameter and replace the name "object" in the JSON object with the name of my Facebook object. Maybe this is obvious to everyone else :0)

Comment: I cannot thank you enough. All of the code autogenerated by facebook & the code in their docs is incorrect. I have spent 4 hours today trying to solve this

Comment: Thanks for this!! I was 99% sure facebook's auto-generated code was wrong. Stackoverflow to the rescue. Now it's 100% sure and I'm up and running. ;)

Answer (score 3):

For anyone struggling with a similar problem on iOS, the sample code again appears to be wrong, however the following seems to work:

```
NSMutableDictionary<FBOpenGraphObject> *object =
[FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPostWithType:@"<appnamespace>:<objecttype>"
    title:@"..."
    image:[result objectForKey:@"uri"]
      url:nil
  description:@"..."];

[FBRequestConnection startForPostOpenGraphObject:object completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
{
    // handle the result
    if ( error ) {
        DLog(@"error %@ creating object", error);
    } else {
        ...
    }
}];
```